# instant searching in petabyte of data

Tags: java, lucene, solr, hadoop

I need to search over petabyte of data in CSV formate files. After indexing using LUCENE, the size of the indexing file is doubler than the original file. Is it possible to reduce the indexed file size??? How to distribute LUCENE index files in HADOOP and how to use in searching environment? or is it necessary, should i use solr to distribute the LUCENE index??? My requirement is doing instant search over petabyte of files....

Comment: What do you mean by "instant" ? If you want to do something in google/yahoo/any search engine style, I would suggest you study their architecture before divind into a solution.

Comment: yep, similar google instant search. But the requirement here is searching the csv file based one the query and draw a chart, as soon as you changed the query, the chart also should change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent off the shelf search engine (like Lucene) should be able to provide search functionality over the size of data you have. You may have to do a bit of work up front to design the indexes and configure how the search works, but this is just config.

You won't get instant results but you might be able to get *very quick* results. The speed will probably depend on how you set it up and what kind of hardware you run on.

You mention that the indexes are larger than the original data. This is to be expected. Indexing usually includes some form of denormalisation. The size of the indexes is often a trade off with speed; the more ways you slice and dice the data in advance, the quicker it is to find references.

Lastly you mention distributing the indexes, this is almost certainly *not* something you want to do. The practicalities of distributing many petabytes of data are pretty daunting. What you probably want is to have the indexes sat on a big fat computer somewhere and provide search services on the data (bring the query to the data, don't take the data to the query).

Comment: Thank you Qwerky. One more doubt, how to integrate lucene with hadoop? I mean in which part can I use Hadoop in Lucene? since the petabyte of data distributed over Hadoop file system only....

Comment: Is it possible to use Map/Reduce in Lucene by integrating with hadoop?

Answer (score 4):

Hadoop and Map Reduce are based on batch processing models.  You're not going to get instant response speed out of them, that's just not what the tool is designed to do.  You might be able to speed up your indexing speed with Hadoop, but it isn't going to do what you want for querying.

Take a look at [Lucandra](http://blog.sematext.com/2010/02/09/lucandra-a-cassandra-based-lucene-backend/), which is a Cassandra based back end for Lucene.  Cassandra is another distributed data store, developed at Facebook if I recall, designed for faster access time in a more query oriented access model than hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid changing your implementation, you should decompose your lucene index into 10, 20 or even more indices and query them in parallel. It worked in my case (I created 8 indices), I had 80 GB of data, and I needed implement search which works on a developer machine (Intel Duo Core, 3GB RAM).