# Lucene Indexing and searching with Map/Reduce

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene, hadoop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [instant searching in petabyte of data…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791602/instant-searching-in-petabyte-of-data)

How to use HADOOP's Map/Reduce in Lucene Indexing and searching?????

Comment: can you specify your question a little bit please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791602/instant-searching-in-petabyte-of-data

Comment: if you have alredy posted thy question, _why_ do you repost it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I could find for you is [Katta](http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/how-katta-works):

> Katta is a distributed application running on many commodity hardware servers very similar to Hadoop MapReduce, Hadoop DFS, HBase, Bigtable or Hypertable.
>
> (...)
>
> Katta supports distributed scoring for its lucene implementation - this is because we do not expect that term distribution is fully balanced over all shards.
>
> Each search query that is done in Katta ends up being two network roundtrips: first we get the document frequencies for a query from all the nodes and on the second trip pass this value and the search query to all nodes. Please note that we also provide a simple count method that just counts documents matching the query but does that within one network roundtrip.